# Sandbox User Change in Mac App Store Login

Tags: cocoa, mac-app-store

I'm testing my app for the Mac App Store.

I've used a Sandbox user and purchased all my in-app purchases.

I want to test with a new Sandbox user, to do all the buys again, but I'm stuck.

On the resulting Mac App Store login window, **how can I change the Sandbox user's Apple ID**? It's grayed out and I can't edit it.

Answer (score 4):

I had to delete the folder:

```
~/Library⁩/⁨Caches/com.apple.appstore⁩
```

and then reboot.

The Apple ID was then editable in the Mac App Store login.

Comment: It helped me to solve the problem with [ productsRequest / didReceive response ] returning zero products. But didn't help in changing the account :)

Answer (score 1):

This clears the sandbox account for the App Store (but not for iCloud or GameCenter), on macOS:

Open App Store app > Preferences (⌘ ,) > Sandbox account > Sign out

Comment: This is working before, but now I can't see this option in the preference window.

Comment: @RRN Maybe you don't have a sandbox account logged in? This still works for me on Big Sur, macOS 11.6

Comment: I logged in, my MacOS is 11.0, it was working before, suddenly it disappeared.