# How do I change the Appstore Sandbox Account on my Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, testing, in-app-purchase, mac-catalyst

I'm working on a Catalyst app, and I'm trying to test its macOS build with a certain sandbox account I recently created (I'm testing in-app purchases). My question is, where do I change the sandbox account on macOS? On iOS 14 it's pretty easy, I just go to the Settings App -> App Store -> SANDBOX ACCOUNT, there I can sign in and out anytime (see the print bellow):

[image: iOS's Sandbox setting]

That means on iOS I can easily change my sandbox account like this, so how can I do the same thing on macOS? Is there an equivalent setting somewhere? I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 by the way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259565/4691224

Answer (score 0):

Open App Store app > Preferences (⌘ ,) > Sandbox account > Sign out